# How to fill the null values using last fill for the same id in PSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a data frame in PostgreSQL as follows and I want the latest record for each id, if any latest record for each id contains a NULL value in any column, I want to replace it with the next latest value within the same column

data

```
id    ingdt         code  gender  address   
1     27-10-2018    NULL  NULL    street1    
1     24-10-2018    1234  NULL    street2
1     20-08-2017    3245  M       street2
2     24-09-2018    NULL  F       Astreet
2     24-10-2018    2857  F       Bstreet
3     24-08-2018    3489  M       NULL
3     22-08-2018    5802  M       Cstreet
```

Expected Output

final_output

```
id    ingdt         code  gender  address   
1     27-10-2018    1234  M       street1   
2     24-10-2018    2857  F       Bstreet
3     24-08-2018    3489  M       Cstreet
```

Tried

```
insert into final_output select * from (
(select code, id from data where code != null order by ingdt limit 1) x join
(select gender, id from data where gender != null order by ingdt limit 1) y join 
(select address, id from data where address != null order by ingdt limit 1)z on y.id=x.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2fc5eced5d5509864a76c050ccca1508)

Using [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) can help you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id, 
    max(ingdt) OVER (PARTITION BY id),
    first_value(code) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY code IS NULL, ingdt DESC) AS code,
    first_value(gender) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY gender IS NULL, ingdt DESC) AS gender,
    first_value(address) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY address IS NULL, ingdt DESC) AS address
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id
```

**Explaining `first_value(...) OVER (...)`**:

A window function can group your rows into separate frames. This is done by the key word `PARTITION BY`. In this case I am generating frames for each `id`.

Now I am checking whether or not the value of a column is `NULL`. This gives me `true` or `false`. I am sorting this result like any `boolean` column with `false` first (meaning `NOT NULL`). If there are many `NOT NULL` rows, the latest row is taken (`ingdt DESC`). This ordering is done for every single frame separately as well.

`first_value()` calculates the first value of the ordered frame.